# Create a custom type of SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, custom-component, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm building a game where the user selects a type of weapon at the start.
I have an SKSword class but I want to be able to set the type it is.
I want to implement it like the following:

```
JBSword *weapon = [[JBSword alloc]initWithSwordType:HeavySword HandelType:Grip];
```

So that I can call:

```
[weapon specialAttack];
```

and it will do an action specific to the sword specified (e.g HeavySword)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1**

What you're trying to do is built into Objective-C. Define a method called `specialAttack` in your `Sword` class:

```
@interface Sword : SKNode

    -(void) specialAttack;

@end
```

Then write a blank implementation:

```
@implementation Sword

    -(void) specialAttack
    {
        return;
    }

@end
```

Now, create a subclass called `HeavySword` using `Sword` as the base class:

```
@interface HeavySword : Sword

    -(void) specialAttack;

@end

...

@implementation HeavySword

-(void) specialAttack
{
    // HeavySword code here
}
```

Now, just create an object of type `HeavySword`:

```
Sword *weapon = [[HeavySword alloc] init];

...

[weapon specialAttack];
```

I'd also suggest using your own prefix other than SK, which implies a class is part of Sprite Kit.

**Option 2**

Use `typedef enum` to define some constants:

```
typedef enum {
    kHeavySwordType,
    kLightSwordType,
    kDualSwordType,
    ...
} SwordType;

typedef enum {
    kWoodHandleType,
    kGoldHandleType,
    kDiamondHandleType,
    ...
} HandleType;
```

You can then declare some properties and an init method in your interface:

```
@interface Sword : SKNode

    @property (nonatomic) SwordType type;
    @property (nonatomic) HandleType handle;

    -(id) initWithType:(SwordType) type handle:(HandleType) handle;

    -(void) specialAttack;

@end
```

Finally, in your implementation:

```
@implementation Sword

-(id) initWithType:(SwordType) type handle:(HandleType) handle
{
    if(self = [super init]) {
        _type = type;     // Use _type within int, and self.type everywhere else
        _handle = handle; // Same thing here.
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) specialAttack
{
    // Code goes here
    // Use self.type and self.handle to access the sword and handle types.
}
```

Comment: When I call [weapon specialAttack] does it call both functions?

Comment: Not unless you call [super specialAttack] in the HeavySword implementation.

Comment: I've encountered a problem. I need to define another property (handle) and having a different subclass for every handle for every sword is ridiculous. (50+ files).

Comment: @JordanBrown Okay, I added another option if subclassing doesn't work for you.